# Add class for all IE browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I need to add a the class "msie" to the html element for all MSIE Browsers. Since IE10 and 11 dosn't support conditionals. I tried different ways but it doesn't work:

First try:

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
   document.documentElement.className+='msie';
}
```

Second try:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent); 
if ( data-useragent=='msie' ) {
   document.documentElement.className+='msie';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a version is use, it sets classes for IE7 to IE10 (*you could add conditional for IE6 etc...*), but it will not give a class to IE11: http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="msie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="msie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="msie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
 <!-->
 <script>if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){document.documentElement.className+=' msie';}</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need the IE11 too.